# php regex match problem multiple line and single line

Tags: php, regex

I need to do multiple regexes in a large text and sometimes they're multiple. My problem is; when I add a regex it works perfectly fine in a short but when it's on a longer one it doesn't find the regex. When add /s to the end to activate "`dot matches newline`", it just breaks the regex because it finds one on from the start and one from the end.

```
preg_match_all('/\[condition](.*?)\[\/condition]*\]/', $content, $result);
```

Example text of not being able to find regex without /s.

> [condition]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel lobortis nisl. Proin ut magna nec eros euismod posuere. Aliquam posuere ornare hendrerit. Praesent non ultrices metus. [somecondition]Duis pretium posuere faucibus.[/somecondition] Etiam feugiat porta diam lacinia pretium. Praesent vestibulum dapibus faucibus. Donec aliquet purus ut erat fermentum, quis tincidunt massa hendrerit.Donec vitae neque gravida, viverra elit vel, lacinia justo. Vivamus sed lacus velit. Curabitur commodo sollicitudin pretium. Sed lobortis urna ac [anothercondition] urna aliquam, eu viverra felis tincidunt. Quisque sagittis consectetur felis sit amet venenatis.[/anothercondition] Donec vel convallis justo, a molestie magna. Phasellus ultrices augue molestie, fringilla quam vel, ornare lorem. Vestibulum nec arcu in orci hendrerit tristique.[/condition]

```
preg_match_all('/\[condition](.*?)\[\/condition]*\]/s', $content, $result);
```

Example text of not being able to find regex with /s.

> [condition]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel lobortis nisl.[anothercondition]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel lobortis nisl. [/anothercondition] [/condition]
> [condition]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel lobortis nisl.[anothercondition]Proin ut magna nec eros euismod posuere. Aliquam posuere ornare hendrerit. Praesent non ultrices metus. Duis pretium posuere faucibus.[/anothercondition] [/condition]
> [condition]Proin ut magna nec eros euismod posuere. Aliquam posuere ornare hendrerit. Praesent non ultrices metus. Duis pretium posuere faucibus.[anothercondition]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel lobortis nisl. [/anothercondition] [/condition]

I'd really appreciate if you can tell me what I'm missing. Thanks

Comment: There's no problem with your pattern except that `*\]` at the end is useless and that `~` as pattern delimiter is a better choice than `/`: https://regex101.com/r/OPvrak/1

Comment: Your question isn't clear and the example string or the pattern don't help to reproduce the problem. Edit your question.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte then you are right, example are bad.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli: Even with an example with newlines, the question (and the problem) remains mysterious.